# About plugin/library/add-on package

Tags: package-management, libraries, click-packages

I found I can install almost everything using terminal.
But how can I get the packaged version of those softwares especially lib files & media codec in case I'm offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the softwares available in the official repositories [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).